# jQuery anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, anonymous

I have some code (below) which I wrote for a small piece of text to fade in out through a cycle of around 4 paragraphs. It works, but whenever I bring up the Web Inspector, it just tells me that it's an 'Anonymous function'. This is really annoying. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Btw, the bit that it hightlights as an anonymous function is:

```
slides[current].fadeOut("slow");
slides[target].fadeIn("slow");
```

The whole extract of code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var About = {
    init: function() {
        var slide_images = $('#widget p')
            slides = new Array(),
            delay = 5,
            current = 0;

        slide_images.each(function(index) {
            current = index;
            slides.push($(this));
        });

        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            target = (current < (slides.length - 1)) ? current + 1 : 0;

            slides[current].fadeOut("slow");
            slides[target].fadeIn("slow");

            current = target;
        }, delay * 750);

    }
} 
About.init();
});
```

I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HmRym/).

Comment: Fix what? What's the problem? What did you expect? I don't see anything wrong on your code nor Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Apart from the lacking comma after `$('#widget p')` which makes those globals of course.

Comment: Yeah, but everytime I bring up the Inspector, it tells me it's an anonymous function. I understand that it's not an error, but how can I stop it from coming up every time I bring up the dev tools?

Comment: Do you have a `console.log` anywhere in your code? Your fiddle and posted code does not generate any message on my console.

Answer (score 1):

Because it *is* an [anonymous function, as opposed to a named function](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Function).

One potential solution could be to roll the code into a named function and reference that function by named for the `init` option.